# React Native Deep link is looping after navigation.reset

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I open my app with deep link on ios (on android is work correctly). After that I define the parameters of deep link and do navigation.reset and deep link started endless loop. how can I clean deep link before starting navigation.reset

Comment: Have  you ever found a solution?